# couldn't authenticate spotify in vercel production

Tags: next.js, spotify, vercel

I made a spotify clone which have a login,main pages. The user is initially directed to login page (localhost:3000/login) and once the user clicks login button they are taken to spotify authentication callback url (from spotify side, we can login using google, facebook or email etc) and once the user is logged in (successfully authenticated) , spotify provides a token which is used to check if the user is authenticated from client side. If success, the user is taken to the main page (which has all the music in it).
The spotify dashboard takes in redirect url for authentication which in my case its -> http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/spotify

This workflow worked perfectly when working and running locally ( localhost:3000 ).

**When hosting in vercel,**

1. I created a project in vercel without envs
2. I took my https://sp-app.vercel.app which is the domain and added to NEXTAUTH_URL into my env, and also added - NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET, NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID and JWT_SECRET
3. Went to spotify dashboard and editing the redirect url to https://sp-app.vercel.app/api/auth/callback/spotify and saved
4. redeployed the app from vercel (which gave me a deployent url, but nevermind) and clicked on the domains --> sp-app.vercel.app
5. The login page came, once I clicked on login button, it loads and stays in login page itself. It isn't moving to my home page nor authenticating but this same code worked locally fine.

**Code to understand :
Login button:**

```
{providers !== null && Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                <div key={provider.name}>
                    <button onClick={()=>signIn(provider.id, {callbackUrl:"/"})}
                        >Login with {provider.name}</button>
                </div>
}
export async function getServerSideProps(){
    const providers = await getProviders(); //getProviders is imported from next-auth

return {
    props:{
        providers,
    }
}
}
```

**middleware:**

```
export async function middleware(req){
    const token = await getToken({req,secret:process.env.JWT_SECRET});

    const {pathname} = req.nextUrl;

    //Allow the request if,
    // (1) Its a request for next-auth session & provider fetching
    // (2) The token exists

    if(pathname.includes('/api/auth') || token){
        return NextResponse.next();
    }

    //Redirect to login if no token or requesting a protected route
    if(!token && pathname !== "/login"){
        return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

While I checked with Network tab, I get a session which should log me in and redirect to main page, but it isn't working in vercel deployment.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console and/or Vercel's logs?

Comment: @juliomalves nope

Comment: This might help: https://leerob.io/blog/spotify-api-nextjs, has a working example in the source code

Answer (score 2):

Hey so first off make sure your NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable is correct. Also check that the redirect URI (from the Spotify developer dashboard) is correct.

After that, add this `secureCookie` code to the getToken function in the _middleware.js file. So that function should end up looking like this:

```
const token = await getToken({
  req,
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  secureCookie:
    process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL?.startsWith("https://") ??
    !!process.env.VERCEL_URL,
});
```

Let me know if this works. I had the same exact issue and this worked for me.